# Offline map with WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

I'm developing an app for windows using WPF project.

In this app I want an offline map of all the France. I have downloaded the osm.pbf file of my country but I don't know how to display it in my app.

I have done some search, I'm supposed to generate the tiles (png or vector) and after add them with my leaflet map.

I'm just wondering how I can render all those tiles (I'm on windows).
Or just if you know a app that can generate them automatically?

Or if you can tell me how i can create a local server that can generate my tiles when i asking them on leaflet it could be ok.

Comment: I don't really know how you're consuming the data but if it's image manipulation you need I'd recommend [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/), it's the best I've found for WPF.

Comment: Downloading raster tiles for a whole country (presumably at all zoom levels above 14) is probably going to be beyond the usage policy for OSM's tile server, not to mention a pretty large storage requirement for your application. I'd go with vector if possible. A cursory look in Google yielded this: http://osm2vectortiles.org/, which might be of interest.

Comment: Like i said i don't want to download all the tiles of a country i have the osm.pbf datas i just need to generate this tiles or find a way to use directly this file on my map

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good question here, though. There's plenty of material on rendeirng, creating tiles on Mapnik, etc. on the OSM wiki and elsewhere on the internet. If you have a specific problem, though, do ask that question. As it stands, it sounds like you're asking for recommendations.